# Django: get a NoReverseMatch while rendering error

Tags: python, django, templates, parameters, django-urls

I seem to be getting a Caught NoReverseMatch error. I am not so sure what is causing the problem. Have a look at the full error.

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'mmc.views.edit_note' with arguments '(1L, '')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

On my get_client page. I have a link to the edit note page. I am assuming the problem might be here in my template. I think the note.pk is the problem.

```
<a href="{% url mmc.views.edit_notes client.pk note.pk %}"> Edit Note</a>
```

Here is also some more information which could help.
**urls.py**

```
(r'^clients/(?P<client_id>\d+)/$', views.get_client),
(r'^clients/notes/(?P<client_id>\d+)(?P<note_id>\d+)$', views.edit_notes),
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit_notes(request, client_id = 0, note_id = 0):
    client = None
    note = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        note = models.Note.objects.get(pk = note_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.NoteForm(request.POST, instance=note)
        if form.is_valid():
            note = form.save(commit=False)
            note.user = request.user
            note.client = client
            note.save(True)
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "Note is successfully added.")
            return HttpResponse("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location = window.opener.location; window.close();</script>")
    else:
        form = forms.NoteForm(instance=note)

    return render_to_response('note_form.html', {'form':form, 'client':client, 'note':note}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**EDIT: ** Seem to have corrected most of it Here are some changes I have made.

**Template**

```
{% for note in notes %}
        <a href="{% url mmc.views.edit_note client.pk note.pk  %}" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"> Edit Note</a>
{% endfor%}
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^clients/notes/(?P<client_id>\d+)/(?P<note_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_note)
```

Now the only problem is it displays all of the links to each edit form notes for an individual client. I only want the link for the latest note and only the latest note. Is there a possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(r'^clients/(?P<client_id>\d+)/$', views.get_client)` should be something like `url(r'^clients/(?P<client_id>\d+)/$', views.get_client, name='MY_URL_NAME')` then called with `{% url MY_URL_NAME client.pk %}`

and import `url` from `django.conf.urls.defaults`

Answer (score 1):

The `client.pk` and `note.pk` are empty values, so they don't match the regex.

Comment: If I just have `<a href="{% url mmc.views.edit_note client.pk %}"> Edit Note</a>` I don't get a non-empty value